# Capturing text from siblings with one xpath expression

Tags: xpath

Suppose I have HTML that contains stuff like this and that I would like to ignore `div`s with `class=log` unless preceded by a `div` with `class=ts`, in which case I would like to capture the text contents of the sibling `div`s in some data structure.

Can one do that and, if so, how please?

```
<div class='log'>start</div>
<div class='ts'>2017-03-14</div><div class='log'>note 1</div>
<div class='ts'>2017-03-15</div><div class='log'>note 2</div>
<div class='log'>start</div>
```

Comment: What exactly did you expect the XPath to return given the above sample HTML?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I work mainly in Python. If it gave me the equivalent of a list of lists? [['2017-03-14', 'note 1'], ['2017-03-15', 'note 2']].

Comment: XPath can't return list of list, just a plain list is possible..

Comment: The closest XPath can get you would be : `['2017-03-14', 'note 1','2017-03-15', 'note 2']`. And that XPath would be about twice as long as the one posted in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XPath returns `div` with `class='log'` that directly preceded by `div` with `class='ts'` :

```
//div[@class='log' and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::div/@class='ts']]
```

I'd break down the potentially confusing part :

- `preceding-sibling::node()[1]` : get a node, of any type (text, element, comment, etc.), that located directly before current context element
- `[self::div/@class='ts']` : validate that that node is a `div` with `class` attribute equals 'ts'

From here you'll need to incorporate the host programming language to proceed to get the desired result, for example, using `lxml` in python :

```
>>> raw = '''<div>
... <div class='log'>start</div>
... <div class='ts'>2017-03-14</div><div class='log'>note 1</div>
... <div class='ts'>2017-03-15</div><div class='log'>note 2</div>
... <div class='log'>start</div>
... </div>'''
>>> from lxml import html
>>> root = html.fromstring(raw)
>>> query = "//div[@class='log' and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::div/@class='ts']]"
>>> [[d.getprevious().text, d.text] for d in root.xpath(query)]
[['2017-03-14', 'note 1'], ['2017-03-15', 'note 2']]
```

---

The following is the XPath that will return `['2017-03-14', 'note 1','2017-03-15', 'note 2']`, as requested :

```
//div[
    (@class='log' and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::div/@class='ts'])
        or
    (@class='ts' and following-sibling::node()[1][self::div/@class='log'])
]/text()
```

Comment: Right, XPath is for *selection*.  Manipulation or transformation of that which is selected generally has to be done in the calling language (XSLT, Python, etc).

Comment: This is in line with my intuition (not my abilities!). I'd be obliged if you could take the time to write the xpath that gives ['2017-03-14', 'note 1','2017-03-15', 'note 2'], if that would not put you to too much trouble!

Comment: @BillBell Done that. Not a trouble at all (explaining the XPath typically requires more effort IMO :p)

Comment: Thanks very much!